# How to enable warning for mismatched typehint for method call?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a method expecting an `int`:

```
/**
 * @param int $someInt
 */
public function methodExpectingInt($someInt)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Yet when called from somewhere only when passing an object into it, a warning will occur in PhpStorm.

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function someMethod()
{
    $this->methodExpectingInt(23); // no warning but as an int everything is fine
    $this->methodExpectingInt(new \Object()); // gets a warning in phpstorm \o/
    $this->methodExpectingInt("this string should issue a warning"); // no warning yet is string
    $this->methodExpectingInt(null); // no warning yet is null
    $this->methodExpectingInt(2.9); // no warning yet is a float
}
```

It will look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the method call and missing warning]

Comment: What PhpStorm version is used? Maybe it's fixed in v9. In any case: there is not extra settings for that -- that's how it currently works (v8.x for sure) -- unfortunately I was unable to locate the ticket (there is definitely one exists for this).

Comment: @LazyOne If it is not a current feature, then I will create a ticket anyway =)

Comment: @LazyOne Currently I use 8.0.3

Comment: @LazyOne If there is a duplicate of this, we will find out: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27591

Comment: Found it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10904